# Error "main.java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, size: 0" and others in Jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

Let me describe the project first.I have a source code in Java Programming language (Not programmed by me and it's in Netbeans IDE) .This program has 4 classes **chkSubmission.class , Parameters.class , Plib.class** and final the **Relation.class** .The program accepts as input a dataset with folder named **"Data"** which contains .zip files and each one of .zip files has C++ source codes.Then it makes some complicated compares and extracts the results in a .txt file with the name **Clustering.txt** inside to folder **"Results"** .The program passes with Success the Clean and Build progress and i got the Jar file that i want to call in HTML with `<object></object>` tag.I test the program with double click and also in Command Line and it produced the results as i expected.BUT after i call it in HTML it didn't produce anything, and if i try to run it with double click it doesn't work.If i try then to run in Command Line i get these errors.Are the parameters also ok to run as an Applet?Please help me .I got confused.The errors are:

```
Exception in thread main.java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:0 Size:0
  at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck<Unknown Source>
  at java.util.ArrayList.get<Unknown Source>
  at gr.edu.teikav.lmous.research.DeltaTbl.max <DeltaTbl.java:37>
  at gr.edu.teikav.lmous.research.ACF.clust<ACF.clust <ACF.java:80>
  at gr.edu.teikav.lmous.research.chkSubmission.submit <chkSubmission.java:113>
  at gr.edu.teikav.lmous.research.chkSubmission.main <chkSubmission.java:122>
```

Code:

**chkSubmission.java**

```
package gr.edu.teikav.lmous.research;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Relation {
    String f1, f2;
    double rel;
    Relation(String fa, String fb, double sim) {
        f1=fa;
        f2=fb;
        rel=sim;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return f1+" "+f2+" "+rel;
    }
}

public class chkSubmission extends Applet{

    public static ArrayList<String> listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
        ArrayList<String> rVal=new ArrayList<>();

       for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                String fName=fileEntry.getName();
                if (fName.endsWith(".zip")) {
                    rVal.add(fName);
                }
            }
        }
       return rVal;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Relation> chk(String inputFolder, String rsltFolder, ArrayList<String> keywordList, double cutOff) throws IOException, Exception {
        File inputF=new File(Parameters.pathOfSources+File.separator+inputFolder);
        ArrayList<String> fileList=listFilesForFolder(inputF);
        ArrayList<Relation> rVal=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> invalidSources=new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<fileList.size()-1; i++) {
            String fi=fileList.get(i);
            if (invalidSources.contains(fi)) continue;
            for (int j=i+1; j<fileList.size(); j++) {
                String fj=fileList.get(j);
                if (invalidSources.contains(fj)) continue;
                //System.out.println(fi+" "+fj);
                try {
                    double sim=Plib.similarity(inputFolder, fi, fj, keywordList, invalidSources);
                    if (sim>cutOff) rVal.add(new Relation(fi,fj,sim));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    if (invalidSources.contains(fi)) break;
                    if (invalidSources.contains(fj)) continue;
                }
            }
        }
        File rFolder=new File(Parameters.pathOfSources+File.separator+rsltFolder);  
        File rFile=new File(rFolder, "invalidSources.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(rFile));
        for (int i=0; i<invalidSources.size(); i++) out.println(invalidSources.get(i));
        out.close();
        return rVal;                
    }

    public static void saveClustering(Graph g, Clustering c, String rsltFolder) throws IOException, Exception {
        File rFolder=new File(Parameters.pathOfSources+File.separator+rsltFolder);  
        File rFile=new File(rFolder, "clustering.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(rFile));
        g.print(out);

        out.println("-- Clustering --");
        //out.println();
        out.println(c);
        out.close();
    }

    public static Clustering submit(String chkFolder, String rsltFolder, ArrayList<String> keywordList, double cutOff, CriterionFunction cF) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Relation> rels=chk(chkFolder, rsltFolder,keywordList,cutOff);

        ArrayList<Vertex> verts=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Link> links=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<rels.size(); i++) {
            Relation cRel=rels.get(i);
            Vertex v1=new Vertex(cRel.f1);
            int v1Idx=verts.indexOf(v1);
            if (v1Idx<0) verts.add(v1);
            Vertex v2=new Vertex(cRel.f2);
            int v2Idx=verts.indexOf(v2);
            if (v2Idx<0) verts.add(v2);
            Link l=new Link(v1,v2,cRel.rel);
            links.add(l);
        }
        Lib.initiateProject();
        Graph g=new Graph(verts, links, chkFolder);
        Clustering c=new ACF().clust(g, cF,0, null);

        saveClustering(g,c,rsltFolder);
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        Parameters.init();
        ArrayList<String> keywordList=Plib.loadKeywords();
        Clustering c=submit("Data", "Results", keywordList, 0.3, new ILR());
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to access the first index (i.e. the first element) of an empty `Arraylist`. Look at class `DeltaTbl` on line `37`.

Comment: Can you suggest a correction to this?

Comment: No and you should ask the programmer of your code first. And look at the mentioned line and try to find the pupose of this method. Maybe there is an error in your provided zip files.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't find the programmer.My teacher gave me the source code and he can't remember which was the programmer and i have only this parameter to complete my thesis in university

Comment: Well, then try to find the reason why the arraylist is still empty, when the programm tries to access the first element.

Comment: For pity's sake, don't post screenshots of textual information!  Copy/paste the ***text*** contained in the command line.

Comment: BTW - you mention an applet but I don't see any applet.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"because i need this to work in web."*  By 'in web' do you really mean 'from a link'?  Why does it need to be embedded in a web page?

Comment: Yes it need to be embedded in a web page because i have a file uploader to upload .zip files and when the uploading of the files will finish, the applet does the compares.

Answer (score 0):

So it runs as an applet? Is the applet signed? If no, it is probably run in a sandbox, and You cannot access the user files.

Heres a short peek:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: Yes it runs but it shows a white screen (because it hasn't GUI) depending on the dimensions of the window.It is signed by Self-Cert in Netbeans Options and i run it locally with XAMPP.